# How can i call another class with MouseListener?

Tags: java, netbeans

how can i call another class using MouseListener?
this my class using Implements MouseListener

```
public class MouseInput implements MouseListener {

@Override
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me){

}

@Override
public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me){

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent me){
    int x = me.getX();
    int y = me.getY();
    if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
    if (x>50 && x<450 && y>400 && y<450){
        if(State.ANIMATED){
            State.ANIMATED = false;
        }else{
            State.ANIMATED = true;
        }
    }
  }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent me){
    State.ANIMATED = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseExited (MouseEvent me){
    State.ANIMATED = false;
}
```

and i want to call other class, anyone can help me?
thank you

Comment: Calling which class? Where? Isn't enough to go for something like: `YourClass.staticMethod();` or `YourClass yc = new YourClass();yc.method();`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the class known to your class MouseInput. 
Create a constructor and a member variable in the class and assign it. Then use from any of the methods you have.

```
    public class MouseInput implements MouseListener { 

    YourClassName yourClassName;

    public MouseInput(YourClassName yourClassName ) {
       this.yourClassName =  yourClassName;
    }
...
```